# react-router-dom passing useState for reusing other routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

So I can't see something react-hooks related here and I don't get the logic a little bit in react component with those passing `state` in routes.

So basically something like this.

```
      <Router>
        <Navbar></Navbar>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/guest" element={<Guest></Guest>}></Route>
          <Route path="/saved" element={<SavedItem></SavedItem>}></Route>
          <Route path="/selectedgallery" element={<SelectedGallery></SelectedGallery>}></Route>
          <Route path="/selectedsavedgallery" element={<SelectedSaveGallery></SelectedSaveGallery>}></Route>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login></Login>}></Route>
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register></Register>}></Route>
          <Route path="/" element={<Gallery></Gallery>}></Route>
          <Route path="/create" element={<CreatePin></CreatePin>}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
```

As you see I have `<Login>` and what I want to do I will pass my useState() in that area and when I get the user I will pass it in my other routes so I could reuse it for users that have login.

I imagine it somehow look like this

```
    const [owner,setOwner] = useState()
    
    ...
   <Route path="/login" element={<Login></Login>} {whatever here to pass the "setOwner" and "owner".} ></Route>
    ...
```

Yes,so I'm passing the props in any routes so that I could reuse it and then other routes can used it for their own purposes.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you basically asking how to pass props to a React component? Can you edit your post to include a more complete code example for what you are trying to accomplish and explain in more detail any issues? See [mcve].

Comment: yes i edited  it is that fine now?

Comment: No, not really. The post still hasn't provided a complete and reproducible code example for what exactly it is you are trying to do, and no question is outright asked and no issue is stated. I'm only inferring from the title and lack of passing any props to routed components that this is what you are trying to ask for help with. If you need help understanding React props, the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) cover that well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setOwner can be passed to the Login element as an parameter

```
<Route path="/login" element={<Login setOwner={setOwner}/>} />
```

in Login

```
function Login({setOwner}) {
  ...
  setOwner("foo");
  ...
}
```